# Have xbmc running on display :0 and a login prompt on display :1

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I have xbmc/kodi running on a machine connected to my TV.  Sometimes, I need to exit xbmc to do some regular computing.  This works fine.

What I'd like to be able to do is have xbmc running on :0 and automatically login and then have a login prompt on :1 (or even automatically log in too) at reboot.

Comment: **Note to close-voters:** this question is not necessarily off-topic. It appears the OP is trying to run two separate login sessions simultaneously. There is nothing in this question to suggest that the OP is _not_ using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

On our HTPC we are running xbmc from a dedicated user account for maximum flexibility.

This allows us to:

- log in passwordless with a remote control to the xbmc user account.
- log in to a different account after boot from lightdm.
- log in to any other account from TTY1 to TTY6 or by switching users.
- keep xbmc setting in a sepatate home for better maintenance.
- possibility to run xbmc on a lean desktop (e.g. GNOME flasback) for little interference.

Unfortunately we had not found a way to configure xbmc/kodi to run fullscreen on one attached monitor, and to simultaneously run a desktop on another attached monitor.

Comment: I wonder if multiseat would work around that limitation...

Comment: @NathanOsman: yeah in case the GPU supports it, or if we had more than one card it may work with multi-seat indeed... configuring it is a challenge. If like me we only occasionally need a desktop it may not be worth it ;)